# inner join is correct or not for these tables?

Tags: oracle

```
create table dpt (
  deptno number, 
  dname varchar2(10), 
  loc varchar2(7)
)

create table emp1 (
  empno number,
  ename VARCHAR2(10),
  desigantion varchar2(10),
  mgr number,
  deptno number
)
```

result 1:

```
111 ram analyst 444 10
222 mohan   clerk   333 20
333 hari    manager 111 10
444 manju   engineer222 30
```

result2:

```
10  inventory   hyd
20  finance         bglr
30  hr          mumbai
```

Now inner joining these two tables:

```
select * from emp1  inner join dept on emp1.deptno=dept.deptno
```

result:

```
111 ram analyst 444 10  10  inventory   hyd
222 mohan   clerk   333 20  20  finance bglr
333 hari    manager 111 10  10  inventory   hyd
```

is it correct or not?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

No. You will get four rows. Means entire rows in tables (If having a joining row in the other table as well) unless otherwise there is a filter to throw out.

See you data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd914/4)

Answer (score -1):

```
      select *.emp1,*.dept from emp1,dept when emp1.deptno=dept.deptno
```